# VueJS child component button changes class of parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a Navigation component with a button to toggle dark mode/light mode. When I click this button, I would like to change a class in the App.vue. How to pass the data from the button to the App.vue?
I believe I have to emit something from the Top Nav and v-bind the class in App.vue, but I don't quite understand how to get it change the class.

When I run this, the button does not change the class on the div.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="[isActive ? 'darkmode' : '']>
    <header>
      <top-nav @change-mode="enableDarkMode"></top-nav>
    </header>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TopNav,
  },
  props: ['isActive'],
  data() {},
  methods: {
    enableDarkMode(isActive) {
      console.log(isActive)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Top Nav Component**

```
<template>
  ...
  <div>
    <button
      :class="[isActive ? 'dark' : 'light']"
      @click="toggle">
        {{ isActive ? "DarkMode" : "LightMode" }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TopNav",
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    };
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      this.$emit('change-mode', this.isActive )
      console.log('emit child')
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet you provided it seems like the `App.vue` has `isActive` props instead of `data` for the method `enableDarkMode` to manage. Vue's props is not to be updated by the component they belong to because of [how the data flow works in Vue props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). With the `App.vue` being the parent of Top Nav component, you probably want it to be like this:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="[isActive ? 'darkmode' : '']>
    <header>
      <top-nav @change-mode="enableDarkMode"></top-nav>
    </header>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TopNav,
  },
  // this is probably not needed because App.vue is the parent component
  // props: ['isActive'],
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    enableDarkMode(isActive) {
      // manages the data
      this.isActive = isActive;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Top Nav component**

```
<template>
  ...
  <div>
    <button
      :class="[isActive ? 'dark' : 'light']"
      @click="toggle">
        {{ isActive ? "DarkMode" : "LightMode" }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TopNav",
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    };
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
      this.$emit('change-mode', this.isActive )
      console.log('emit child')
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should rename isActive in App.vue in something like darkModeEnabled. The same name in both components is confusing.
Also there is no need to keep isActive in the Nav state. You can pass the value of darkModeEnabled as a prop to TopNav and then emit the opposite of this prop value when toggle() is called.

Comment: @fdglefevre Yes I agree, naming with clarity is important, but OP is asking why the class in App.vue is not updating so I'm trying to address just that.

Comment: @fdglefevre I am interested in your solution, could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @fdglefevre thank you, I'll look into this hopefully it will help me understand props and emits a bit better.